# SQL connection string for importing SO data sump

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection-string

I'm trying to use Sam Saffron's program SoSlow (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999185/is-there-a-script-or-program-that-will-efficiently-and-quickly-load-up-the-so-dum)) for importing SO's data sump into MS SQL Server 2008.
Unfortunately, I have little idea of what I'm doing, and so do not know the Connection String that the program asks for.

I have tried the following syntax:

Data Source=SHIMI\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=SO; User Id=sa; Password=;

where SHIMI is the name of my machine, and SO is the name of the DB I've created.
SoSlow announces that the login fails "Login failed for user 'sa'".
Tried all other logins that are listed through the object browser in SQL Server Management Studio > Security > logins.
I have not altered the server in any way since install, defaults apply.

What am I doing wrong? (besides asking noob questions)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have set an `SA` password during the installation of SQL Server Express - if you don't recall it you will need to reset it. Follow the steps [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/13/10029240/reset-sa-pwd-in-sql-server-2005-express.aspx) to reset.

Comment: welp actually the server was installed with Windows Authentication only, I used this connection string
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
and it worked :)